# Freeze existing properties of object, but allow object to be extensible

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have been looking at `Object.freeze()` and `Object.seal()`.

`Object.freeze()` - will make all existing properties non-writable, and will not allow any new properties to be added.

`Object.seal()` - "Sealing an object prevents new properties from being added and marks all existing properties as non-configurable."

I am looking for a way to make all *existing* properties "frozen" (non-writable), but allow new properties to be added.

Is there shorthand for doing that?

The manually way of doing what I want is:

```
let freezeExistingProps = obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
     Object.defineProperty(obj, k, {
         writable: false
      });
  });
};
```

The above function works surprisingly well to freeze existing top-level properties on an object (it doesn't overwrite them, just changes them to non-writable), but I am hoping there might be a more official/quicker way to do the above.

Comment: Umm... Interesting... But not that I have heard of exists in JavaScript.

Comment: yeah, I am really surprised that this doesn't exist as an official method on Object (such as `Object.freezeExistingProps(obj)`, but the manual way works...

Comment: Out of curiosity what is your use case for this?

Comment: I need to share objects, but I don't want existing properties to be modified after sharing. For example, imagine a static property X on a superclass, you want to share its data among all instances, but you don't want child instances to modify X or any subproperties of X.

Comment: Hmm, but in the current manner this `writeable:false` is revert able right?

Comment: You may use [fast-freeze](https://github.com/node-muneem/fast-freeze) library without compromising performance. However since you can't add properties once it is freezed, you may write a wrapper to recreate with new properties.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to do it in the manner of freeze, then freezing it immediately, and setting up to a prototype of another object might help, but it will return a copy (pointing to the original object as prototype), exactly in the form how you want. there are obviously some pros and cons, as the properties will not be the immediate properties, but we can find it out by its `__proto__` if we need all the keys (assuming you have a dedicated use case)

So, just another try

```
function freezeExistingProps (obj){
    var OBJECT = function(){};
    Object.freeze(obj)
    OBJECT.prototype = obj;
    return new OBJECT();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might do the following:

```
instance -> frozen static proto -> dynamic proto
```

Some sample:

```
function freeze(stat,dyn){
  Object.setPrototypeOf(stat,dyn);
  Object.freeze(stat);
}

var a={unchangeable:1};
var b={changeable:2}
freeze(a,b);
```

Now have a look at *a* and change some *b* props.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider cloning your object into a new one with extra attribute. It's also a very good practice (look for **immutability**).

An example:

```
const setAge = (person, age) => ({ ...person, age });

const person = {
  firstName: 'Luke',
  lastName: 'Skywalker',
};

const personWithAge = setAge(person, 24);
```

Comment: Yes but I need to clone an arbitrary object. And, not only that, but I need to do a deep clone, not a shallow clone. In your example, if person or age is an object, it will keep the references to the original object.